# "cannot reserve arena virtual address space" while compiling Golang on OpenBSD

Tags: go

I'm getting the error "cannot reserve arena virtual address space" while compiling golang on OpenBSD with command "ksh all.bash" (also tried make.bash but didn't work). This is the output:

```
$ ksh all.bash
# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist

# Building compilers and Go bootstrap tool for host, openbsd/386.
lib9
libbio
... (truncated)
pkg/go/doc
pkg/go/build
cmd/go
throw: runtime: cannot reserve arena virtual address space
```

I tried following the directions on http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/OpenBSD, but it is also possible I didn't do it correctly. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like rather than screwing with the "staff" group, changing the defaults for the "default" section solved the issue.

```
default:\
    :path=/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/X11R6/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin:\
    :umask=022:\
    :datasize-max=infinity:\
    :datasize-cur=infinity:\
    :maxproc-max=256:\
    :maxproc-cur=128:\
    :openfiles-cur=128:\
    :stacksize-cur=4M:\
    :localcipher=blowfish,6:\
    :ypcipher=old:\
    :tc=auth-defaults:\
    :tc=auth-ftp-defaults:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program fails to allocate virtual address space

http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/malloc.goc#374

I do not use OpenBSD myself, and do not know what your problem is. But you could try and gather more information yourself, if you insert some printouts here:

http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/mem_openbsd.c#54

Alex